# headers missing in HTTP response with Nginx+uWsgi+Web.py

Tags: python, nginx, web.py, uwsgi

all,

My evironment is Nginx+uWsgi+Web.py. And I got the following HTTP response:

```
   Connection   keep-alive
   Date Mon, 28 Oct 2013 09:02:50 GMT
   Server   nginx
   Transfer-Encoding    chunked
```

However, the response is supposed to be like this produced by Apache+mod_wsgi:

```
   Connection   Keep-Alive
   Content-Encoding gzip
   Content-Length   26225
   Content-Type text/html; charset=UTF-8
   Date Mon, 28 Oct 2013 08:08:33 GMT
   Keep-Alive   timeout=15, max=100
   Server   Apache
   Vary *
```

So, there are a lots of header missing. Can't figure out....

My nginx config is like:

```
http {
    charset utf-8;

    # Set the mime-types via the mime.types external file
    include mime.types;

    # And the fallback mime-type
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    #default_type text/html;

    # Click tracking!
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    # Hide nginx version
    server_tokens off;

    # ~2 seconds is often enough for HTML/CSS, but connections in
    # Nginx are cheap, so generally it's safe to increase it
    keepalive_timeout 20;

    # You usually want to serve static files with Nginx
    sendfile on;

    tcp_nopush on; # off may be better for Comet/long-poll stuff
    tcp_nodelay off; # on may be better for Comet/long-poll stuff

    server_name_in_redirect off;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    gzip on;
    gzip_http_version 1.0;
    gzip_comp_level 5;
    gzip_min_length 512;
    gzip_buffers 4 8k;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types
        # text/html is always compressed by HttpGzipModule
        text/css
        text/plain
        text/x-component
        application/javascript
        application/json
        application/xml
        application/xhtml+xml
        application/x-font-ttf
        application/x-font-opentype
        application/vnd.ms-fontobject
        image/svg+xml
        image/x-icon;

    # This should be turned on if you are going to have pre-compressed copies (.gz) of
    # static files available. If not it should be left off as it will cause extra I/O
    # for the check. It would be better to enable this in a location {} block for
    # a specific directory:
    # gzip_static on;

    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_vary on;

    # Upstream to abstract backend connection(s) for PHP
    upstream php {
        server unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
    }
    server {
        ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
        listen 80 default;
        ## listen for ipv6
        #listen [::]:80 default ipv6only=on; 

        # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
        server_name localhost;
        server_name_in_redirect off;
        charset utf-8;
        access_log  /log/access.log;
        error_log   /log/error.log debug;
        root /home/www;
        index index.html index.htm index.php;
        location ~ \.php$ { .... }

        location / {
            uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/uwsgi.sock;
            include uwsgi_params;
        }

}
```

And my uWsgi config is:

```
[uwsgi]
plugins = python2
chdir = /home/pycode
module = code 
processes = 2
max-requests = 5000
chmod-socket = 666
master = True
vacuum = True
disable-logging = True
enable-threads = True
socket = /tmp/uwsgi.sock
pidfile = /run/uwsgi.pid
workers = 4
reload-mercy = 8
uid = http
gid = http
```

The python code over web.py is using Jinja2 template without anything special and run well in Apache+mod_wsgi.

By the way, the nginx+php-fpm produce right response in my case. So I guess the problem is with uwsgi configuration.

Any help?

Thanks in advcance.

Comment: it is not clear if the app is not working, or you simply want gzip compression (something is not happening from the logs you pasted)

Answer (score 0):

Since the headers you're *missing* are added by the webserver there are no *headers missing*. Each configuration (httpd+modwsgi and nginx+uwsgi) sends some headers by default unless configured.

Comment: Well, I guess I asked the wrong question. So httpd+mod_wsgi adds more default headers than nginx+uwsgi does. Then question is, how can I changed the config of header addition for nginx+uwsgi, since, for example, I can't even find in the uwsgi document the command to add a content-type header?

Comment: I noticed the missing `content-type` too. This normally is responsibility of the wsgi framework (web.py in your case) (apache probably adds a default text/html). I don't use it so i really don't know, sorry. :(

Answer (score 0):

I came across this and it was because the missing header's value was unquoted. A pure curl request showed the header. Whereas Python Requests, Charles and httpie did not display the header with the unquoted value (in my case it was an ETag header).